# Error install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 (unmet dependencies)

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

When i try to install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4, i getting error message like below :

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: liblwgeom-2.4-0 (>= 2.4.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

Whats is going on ? Anyone please help me  :?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please do not put "Solved" into the question. Add an answer and accept that. That's the only way to mark a question as "resolved"

Comment: Thanks your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This has **Solved**. And this my **Solution** :

1. First this my fault, when i install postgresql-9.6 use xenial distribution but when i try install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 i use trusty distribution.
2. I try reinstall with same distribution, use trusty distribution.
3. If you use repository, dont forget to edit source.list on `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list`
4. I find solution from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/postgresql?dist=trusty-pgdg)